# how to infer alpha value from pair of opaque images

Tags: math, glsl, alpha

I have two images, one with a white background, and one with a black background, I want to convert these images into one semi transparent image

I have found that

```
color*alpha=blackBackgroundImage
color*alpha+(1-alpha)=whiteBackgroundImage
```

I want a function that takes blackBackgroundImage and whiteBackgroundImage and outputs the color and the alpha

I'm bad at math

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with programming.  It should be on [math.se].  But: `black-white=alpha-1`.

Comment: @Teepeemm I know it could be a general math question, but I'm looking for a glsl specific solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to solve the system of equations:

```
    color*alpha=blackBackgroundImage
<=> color = blackBackgroundImage / alpha
```

Plugging that into the second equation:

```
    blackBackgroundImage / alpha * alpha + (1 - alpha)*(1,1,1) = whiteBackgroundImage
<=> blackBackgroundImage + (1 - alpha)*(1,1,1) = whiteBackgroundImage
<=> (1 - alpha)*(1,1,1) = whiteBackgroundImage - blackBackgroundImage
```

So `alpha` should be `1 + blackBackgroundImage.r - whiteBackgroundImage.r`. The same applies to any other channel.

Comment: What about color? How do I get the color?
c=b/(b-w+1) ?

Comment: Once you have calculated `alpha`, you can use the second formula to calculate `color`.